# Can "precise" be used as a verb? Was it ever used much as a verb?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, history

I found this in
[the writings of 19th century economist Francis Ysidro Edgeworth](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=s7cJAAAAIAAJ&q=%22To%20precise%20the%20ideas%22&dq=%22To%20precise%20the%20ideas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq0pXXtqLPAhUUI2MKHcCcDeIQ6AEIITAB):

> To precise the ideas ...

Was "precise" ever used much as a verb? 
Can and should we use it as a verb today?

Research findings:

- *préciser* means *to clarify* in French. 
  In English we use verbs such as *specify* and *detail*
  to mean what the French mean by *préciser*.
    <sup>— [provided by](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349751/can-precise-be-used-as-a-verb#comment809943_349751) [David Handelman](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191998/david-handelman),
  [supplemented by](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349751/can-precise-be-used-as-a-verb#comment810052_349751) [Drew](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/51214/drew)</sup>
- It turns out that [F Y Edgeworth](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Edgeworth.html)’s mother was Catalan,
  his father died when he was two
  and he was educated at home in Ireland up to entering university. 
  Not having much knowledge of Spanish
  I wonder whether ‘to precise’ is an Anglicisation
  of a Spanish, or possibly Catalan, verb. 
  It’s also worth noting that the ultimate root of [precise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=precise)
  is a Latin verb even though we use it only as an adjective.
        <sup>— [provided by](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349751/can-precise-be-used-as-a-verb#comment810011_349751) [BoldBen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191850/boldben)</sup>

Comment: That just looks like a mistake to me.  AFAIK there is no verb "to precise".

Comment: It looks like a gallicism: *préciser* means *to clarify*. And it looks wrong in English (to me).

Comment: I looked up [F Y Edgeworth](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Edgeworth.html), of whom I'd never heard, and it turns out that his mother was Catalan, his father died when he was two and that he was educated at home in Ireland up to entering university. Not having much knowledge of Spanish I wonder whether 'to precise' is an anglicisation of a Spanish, or possibly Catalan, verb. It's also worth noting that the ultimate root of [precise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=precise) is a latin verb even though we use it only as an adjective.

Comment: The full OED defines the verb [**to precise**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149662?rskey=SvLBxc&result=1#eid) as *To make precise or definite; to define precisely or exactly; to particularize. **Now rare**.*

Comment: What @DavidHandelman said. It is French. In English we use verbs such as *specify* and *detail* to mean what the French mean by *preciser*.

Comment: In addition to French, it also works great in Spanish.

Answer (score 9):

In a comment, FumbleFingers answered:

> The full OED defines the verb [**to precise**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149662?rskey=SvLBxc&result=1#eid) as *To make precise or definite; to define precisely or exactly; to particularize. **Now rare**.*

Comment: Superb research @FumbleFingers. I wonder how rare it was in Edgworth's time.

Comment: The -ing form occurs in modern use in the term 'precising definition' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precising_definition)]. An important usage on ELU. When one sense is chosen from the usual array of polysemes (eg the mathematician's definition of 'similar'), or when arbitrary prescriptions are made to a default sense (eg from the Wiki. article: 'From a class syllabus: "Class participation" means _attending class, listening attentively, answering and asking questions, and participating in class discussions_,' we have a _precising definition_. Thus the need to _define one's terms_.

Answer (score 2):

In medical terminology 'precise'  can be used as a verb. For example, neurologists and ethicists have used it as  a verb as in 'to precise the definition of brainstem death'.

Comment: Do you have any citations to back you up? I've never seen it used like that before. (Admittedly not a neurologist)

Comment: I first saw it  several years ago in a comment by the  editor of   the Jn of Medical Ethics referring to  an author who had used it this  way. Since then I have used it in several publication  as it is useful in showing  how brain death as a concept was precised into  brainstem death.

Answer (score 0):

In Catalan (and Spanish), the verb *precisar*, meaning "to specify; to state precisely" does exist:

> **PRECISAR** *v.*: cast. *precisar*.
>   || **1.** *tr.* Determinar d'una manera precisa.
>
> > *Més aviat pels voltants, rera, no puc precisar*, Espriu Lab. 20.

- http://dcvb.iec.cat/results.asp?word=precisar

Wikipedia makes [un-cited] mention that *precise* as a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precise#Verb) in English is *"... used by non-native speakers..."*.

So it seems probable that is was a calque from Catalan, or it may be an archaic usage of "to precise" in English (see Google Ngrams results for ["precised"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=precised&year_start=1845&year_end=1926&corpus=15&smoothing=3)), however, note that if precise ever existed as an anglicised verb it already seemed continental in flavour by Edgeworth's time:

> *... the railroads had outlined, "precised", as the French say, the real fundamentals of the difficulties of the railroads...*

- [Review of Reviews and World's Work, Volume 50](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hC0IAQAAIAAJ&q="precised"), Albert Shaw, 1914

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to precise that I have no qualifications in this area".  Does NOT have the same meaning as "I would like to specify that I have no qualifications in this area".  "Precise" meaning to make quite clear, wheras "specify" implies which among several choices is the one you mean.  Yes I speak French fluently, but it's not my mother tongue so I do not think that has influenced me, yet I have always used "to precise" in all its conjugations.